# Why am I getting incorrect results when trying to find the type of 'number' in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, typeof

There is another question about typeof. It does not cover these examples.

Why won't typeof work on the 0 in the first filter() with arrNew?

It works in the second filter() with arrNew02.

It does recognize 0 as typeof "number" if I put a console.log statement before the return inside the if statement.

```
function filterArray(arr){

var arrNew = arr.filter(function(item){
    if(typeof item === "number"){
      console.log("typeof item: " + item +  " " + typeof item);
      return item;
    }
  });


console.log("arrNew: " +  arrNew);

var arrNew02 = arr.filter(function(item){
    return(typeof item === "number");
});

console.log("arrNew02: " + arrNew02);

}

filterArray([1, "a", "b", 0, 15]);
// This should return [1, 0, 15]
```

I tried using isNaN. But, it missed on a number that is a string in this example. It will return the "1".

```
var arrNew03 = arr.filter(function(item){
    if(isNaN(item) === false){
      return item;
    }
});

console.log("arrNew03: " + arrNew03);


filterArray([1, 2, "aasf", "1", "123", 123]);
// This should return [1, 2, 123]
```

So, what is the best way to look for the type of an item?
Are there different ways for numbers, strings, etc?
I did read the MDN documentation. At the very end, it has a link to why typeof isn't safe anymore. But, I don't think that linked discussion is relevant here.
http://es-discourse.com/t/why-typeof-is-no-longer-safe/15

Comment: You're misunderstanding what the `filter()` callback should return.

Comment: Yes - I am seeing a little bit of what is going on by reading the answers below and reading the MDN page with the links provided in the answers below.

Comment: From MDN:   Function is a predicate, to test each element of the array. Return true to keep the element, false otherwise, taking three arguments. I am returning the item.

Comment: OK - I got it from reading the MDN documentation and everything here. The filter() method will include an item in the new array if you return true. In my code, the code/filter() method that doesn't work is returning the item, not true. But, if you return 0, the filter() method evaluates that as a Falsey item, and returns false. So, the item is not included in the new array. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) needs a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value for including the element in the new array.

A return of the item with value of zero does not include this item.

> **Description**
>
> `filter()` calls a provided callback function once for each element in an array, and constructs a new array of all the values for which `callback` returns [a value that coerces to `true`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy). `callback` is invoked only for indexes of the array which have assigned values; it is not invoked for indexes which have been deleted or which have never been assigned values. Array elements which do not pass the `callback` test are simply skipped, and are not included in the new array.

Comment: OK - I got it from reading the MDN documentation and everything here. The filter() method will include an item in the new array if you return true. In my code, the code/filter() method that doesn't work is returning the item, not true. But, if you return 0, the filter() method evaluates that as a Falsey item, and returns false. So, the item is not included in the new array. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The number `0` is the only number that becomes casted to the boolean `false`. All other numbers cast to `true`. If you return `item` for your filter result, and `item` resolves to `false` (which it will if `item === 0`) then the item will be filtered out.

You need to return `true` instead of `item` in your first `arr.filter` call.

Comment: OK - I got it from reading the MDN documentation and everything here. The filter() method will include an item in the new array if you return true. In my code, the code/filter() method that doesn't work is returning the item, not true. But, if you return 0, the filter() method evaluates that as a Falsey item, and returns false. So, the item is not included in the new array. Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm sorry, Gershom. I can only tick one answer with the green checkmark. I am giving it to Nina because she gave me the links. Hope you're OK with that.

Comment: I FORGIVE YOU :')